# Can I get a stacktrace from a CLR exception without attaching the VS debugger?

Tags: .net, debugging, iis-6, windbg

I have a website running on a remote server, and want to get some information from an exception that is occurring.  I can't install VS or use remote debugging, and have been trying to use various versions of WinDbg with little success.  In my local tests, I can get WinDbg to break on a C++ exception, or a CLR exception that I threw, but can't get much more information than 'something was thrown'.

Is WinDbg the way to go, or is there another way, or am I screwed for not having adequate logging?

Comment: I'd say you need better logging, yes

Comment: I would setup [adplus](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2009/05/18/capturing-adplus-clr-crashes.aspx) temporarily to create a minidump whenever an exception is thrown, then look at the minidump with WinDbg.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Attach WinDbg to the process, then enter these commands:

```
.symfix
sxe clr
sxd av
.loadby sos clr
g
```

The execution will continue (after go command) and will break whenever CLR exception is thrown (or any other unhandled exception). Whenever it breaks on CLR exception you see:

```
(xxxx.xxxx): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
```

Then you can use SOS commands like `!pe` to print out exception type, `!ClrStack` to dump stack, `!dso` to dump managed objects in the stack, etc.

EDIT: I had typos in `sxe` and `sxd` commands. Thanks to @MStodd for noticing that.

Comment: I'm going to try it on my messed up machine later, but it's looking good.  It looks like for .NET 2.0, I need to `.loadby sos mscorwks` instead of `.loadby sos clr`.  That sound right?

Comment: @MStodd, that should work too. In .Net 2.0 you can use `mscorwks` or `mscorsrv` (for server mode applications), while in .Net 4.0 you can use `mscoreei`. 'clr` is just a shortcut to the current execution engine. I noticed sometimes `clr` does not work, and in this case it is fine to use `mscoreei` or `mscorwks` or `mscorsrv`.

Comment: @SevaTitov May I ask why you are recommending disabling breaks on access violations? (sxd av) Quite often a managed NullReferenceException initially manifests itself as an AV, so I would think that it would be desirable to enable breaking on these.

Comment: @Dono, from what I understand, in some cases CLR causes AV as some sort of internal mechanism, probably related to memory probes. Each instance of that AV is internally handled by CLR itself, so there is no side-effects for application. Please note, that `sdx av` disables automatic break on first chance exception, not second. If there is actual problem with your code that causes AV, it would likely manifest itself with second chance exception, and windbg will break as usual and allow you investigate the problem.

Comment: I've got the new Windows Store version of WinDbg.  I can't figure out how to execute these commands.